# Jump to the line which says `modifed...` while using :Gstatus in vim-fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I used `:Gstatus` and can see the status window. How do I directly jump to the line which say that a file has been modified.

```
# On branch refactor-modeldatasource
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   graphos/sources/model.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I am on the first line and want to jump to the line which says `modified ......`.

Comment: What about [reading the documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L33)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about just pressing :

```
/modi<enter>
```

?

or if you have activated relative linenumber, you could just press `5j`

edit

if you meant the shortcut mapping in fugitive, try `<C-N>` in that Gstatus buffer.

Comment: As I can recall, there is a one or two keystroke shortcut for it.

Answer (score 6):

`:help Gstatus` says its

```
                    <C-N> next file
                    <C-P> previous file
```

for next and previous files. Maybe this is it?